# stanford dependencies list

Tags: dependencies, stanford-nlp

Is there a way to have a list of all type of Stanford Dependencies?

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml

Answer (score 3):

What do you think is missing?  For the basic dependencies, the list in the manual should be complete.  If not, that's a bug.

For the collapsed dependencies, in the main the same should apply, but it's more complex because two dependencies (prep_* and conj_*) really have an open slot.  While prepositions and conjunctions are often regarded as closed parts of speech, there isn't any pregenerated list of fillers.  Anything analyzed as a preposition or conjunction by the parser will fill that slot.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little late, but I was looking for this same thing and found the list: http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Dependency_relations#Standard_list_of_dependency_relations

This is also available in the back of the Stanford Dependencies Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Stanford Dependencies Manual](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf).  It lists all dependencies with short explanations and examples.  Be aware that newer versions of the Stanford Parser might use slightly different dependencies (usually more specialized ones)

Comment: Yes I know about this manual, but I would like to have a list of ALL the relations! :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all the relations"

Comment: I mean all the type of relations that exist! The current representation contains approximately 53 grammatical relations, I want a list of all of them. I wrote already a list but I wanna know if there is a method with which I can extract all of them!

Comment: I do not know of such a list.  Maybe ask directly from the Stanford team.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the list of dependencies for the newer versions (3.5.2 and newer) of the Stanford dependency parser, take a look at the [Universal dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/) and there in particular the [English grammatical relations page](http://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/)

This is linked in the manual.